# How to align weeks in different years in ggplot2?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

How can I align the weeks from different years on the x-axis so that weeks occurring in the same month, like June, are aligned?

Please note that data was not collected during same weeks in different years, so some weeks can't be aligned, and that's okay. I just wish to align weeks that occurred in the same months in different years to compare temporal patterns of counts across different weeks in different years.

Here is my code:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = date_in, y = total_count, fill = Treatment)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(year ~ .) +  # Stacking years on top of each other
  theme_few(base_size = 10, base_family = "Arial") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, 
                                   vjust = 0.5, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(vjust = 0.5, color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(color = "black"),  
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black")) + 
  facet_wrap(~ year, ncol = 1, scales = "free", 
                     strip.position = "right") + # Righty-axis
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("IP" = "blue", "LD" = "red"))  # Set custom colors

# Print the plot
print(p)
```

[image]

Here is the reproducible example dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(date_in = structure(c(7L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 
15L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 21L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 
13L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 20L, 23L, 23L, 26L, 26L, 28L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("03/08", "04/05", 
"04/26", "05/17", "05/19", "05/24", "05/26", "05/31", "06/02", 
"06/07", "06/09", "06/14", "06/16", "06/21", "06/23", "06/28", 
"06/29", "06/30", "07/05", "07/06", "07/07", "07/12", "07/13", 
"07/14", "07/19", "07/21", "07/26", "07/28", "08/02", "08/04", 
"08/09", "08/11", "08/16", "08/17", "08/24", "08/25", "08/31", 
"09/01", "09/07", "09/08", "09/14", "09/15", "09/21", "09/22", 
"09/23", "09/28", "09/29", "09/30", "10/05", "10/06", "10/07", 
"10/12", "10/13", "10/14", "10/19", "10/20", "10/21", "10/26", 
"10/27", "10/29", "11/02", "11/03", "11/04", "11/09", "11/11", 
"11/17", "11/23", "12/01", "12/07"), class = "factor"), total_count = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 362L, 135L, 
684L, 34L, 123L, 6L, 21L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 11L, 0L, 12L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L), Treatment = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L), levels = c("between_row", "IP", 
"mulch", "LD"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"
), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```

My desired output will look like below

[image]

Comment: Would it work to get week numbers and compare those? Or are the dates super important?

Comment: Why do you have 5/19/2011 aligned with 5/17/2013? What's the rule for that? Couple of days before and after? Or what? Your desired output even shows 6/02 and 6/29 aligned!!!!

Comment: Do you need those dates on the bottom of each graph? That's doable, but would take more time than I have right now. If not, we can align the weeks based on their week number.

Comment: Thank you very much. It does look cleaner, all weeks should appear on x-axis because if there are no dates/weeks it would imply that no sampling was done in those weeks. And we don't need numbers below graph - dates within the column are sufficient. You don't need to spend time on it because I got the answer, but just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps a round about way of doing it using `patchwork`. Essentially, plotting each with breaks as the week number and re-applying start-week dates as labels so the plots line up:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

dates_weeks <- df |>
  mutate(date = mdy(paste0(date_in, year)),
         week = week(date)) 

min_week <- min(dates_weeks$week)
max_week <- max(dates_weeks$week)

year_breaks <- 2010:2013 |>
  set_names() |>
  map(\(year_n) {
    
    year_dat <- dates_weeks |> 
      filter(year == year_n) |> 
      select(date_in, week) |> 
      unique()
    
    week_map <- character(max_week - min_week + 1)
    names(week_map) <- seq(min_week, max_week)
    
    week_map[as.character(year_dat$week)] <- as.character(year_dat$date_in)
    
    
    week_map
    
  })

library(patchwork)

dates_weeks |>
  mutate(week = factor(week), Treatment = factor(Treatment)) |> 
  nest(data = -year) |>
  mutate(pl = map2(data, year, \(data, year) {
    # browser()
    
    ggplot(data, aes(x = week, y = total_count, fill = Treatment)) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_x_discrete(
        labels = year_breaks[[as.character(year)]],
        drop = FALSE
      ) +
      facet_wrap(year, strip.position = "right") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("IP" = "blue", "LD" = "red"), drop = FALSE) +
      theme_few(base_size = 10)
    
  })) |>
  pull(pl) |>
  wrap_plots(ncol = 1) +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect") &
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      angle = 90,
      hjust = 1,
      vjust = 0.5,
      color = "black"
    ),
    axis.text.y = element_text(vjust = 0.5, color = "black"),
    axis.title = element_text(color = "black"),
    strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: How does edited code look? Have started by filtering out the 0 observation weeks.

Comment: Oh I see! You mean in weeks where counts were zero you expect an empty bar on that graph but no labels underneath the same week in the other ones? So `03/08` and `04/05` should appear on the lowest graph but above them should be empty spaces with no labels?

Comment: How is the above code? I have given each facet a unique set of named values as week breaks to line up week numbers across years. The key things in the above graph is that it puts `2010/07/07` and `2012/07/06` as the same week and `2011/05/19` and `2013/05/17` as the same week, even though dates differ. Which is I think what you want and that other methods were struggling to manage?

Comment: Sorry had forgotten to take out the filtering statement. Have updated above - this currently lines up week by week number in year. The last question I suppose is whether `06/09` in top graph should line up with `06/09` in second graph (same week of year) or `06/02` in second graph and `06/29` in third (all first June observations in each year)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Update:

If you need to align the dates based on their date number, then we need to get the week number and use that in `ggplot`.

I am not aware of a way to have custom axis tick labels within facets, so I just used the week number on the axis and added labels for the actual dates. You can create multiple plots and patch them together though.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
  
df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character),
         week_no = strftime(paste(year, date_in, sep = "/"), format = "%V")) %>% 
  filter(total_count != 0) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(week_no, year, date_in), 
              names_from = c(Treatment), values_from = c(total_count)) %>% 
  full_join(expand.grid(week_no = unique(.$week_no), year = unique(.$year)), .) %>% 
  replace_na(., list(date_in = "", LD = 0, IP = 0)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(LD:IP, names_to = "Treatment", values_to = "total_count") %>% 
  mutate(date_in = ifelse(Treatment == "IP", date_in, "")) %>% 
 ggplot(., aes(x = week_no, y = total_count, fill = Treatment)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(y=0, label=date_in), vjust=-0.5, color = "darkgray") +
  facet_wrap(~ year, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y", strip.position = "right") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("IP" = "navyblue", "LD" = "darkred")) +
  xlab("Week no.") + ylab("Total Count") +
  theme_few(base_size = 10, base_family = "Arial") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, 
                                   vjust = 0.5, color = "black"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(vjust = 0.5, color = "black"),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"),
        legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

###### Original Answer:

You can filter out the empty rows and use `free_x` to only show the `date_in` ticks that have a `total_count`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(df[df$total_count != 0,], aes(x = date_in, y = total_count,
                                     fill = Treatment)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ year, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y", strip.position = "right") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("IP" = "blue", "LD" = "red")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, 
                                   color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(vjust = 0.5, color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(color = "black"),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"),
        legend.position = "top") +
  theme_few(base_size = 10, base_family = "Arial")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>